# Issues with camel case using JQuery with data- attribute

Tags: jquery

I had this code working all right, until I transitioned from "_" to camel case. Here is the code:

```
//Selecting the form id
formSelector = "#" + formId; 

//Selecting all input/select/textarea fields with data- attributes
elementSelector = formSelector + " input[data-errArrow], " + 
  formSelector + "      select[data-errArrow],     " + formSelector 
  +  " textarea[data-errArrow]";

//For each selected element...
$(elementSelector).each(function(index,element) {
  console.log($(this).prop("tagName"));
  console.log($(this).attr("data-errArrow"));
  console.log($(this).data("errArrow"));
  ...
 }
```

The console output is:

```
INPUT
mylib.js:25 R
mylib.js:26 undefined
```

If data-errArrow attribute's value is correctly displayed as "R", should .data of that element not also show the same result? Why is it undefined. There is some discussion [here](https://api.jquery.com/data/) on camel case in the JQuery docs related to the data- attribute. It says:

"In case no data is stored with the passed key, jQuery searches among the attributes of the element, converting a camel-cased string into a dashed string and then prepending data- to the result. So, the string lastValue is converted to data-last-value."

I do not see how this could be applicable above. I need to fix this. I want .data to return 'R' in the example.

Comment: The correct mode is `data-err-arrow`. Why simply don't you change your attributes?

Comment: However you can try data with the correct mode: `$(this).dataset.errArrow`

Comment: @Marcos Perez Gude, the native .dataset is not supported by older browsers. I may just revert back to non-camelCase as you suggested.

Comment: Got it to work by reverting back.  Still an explanation would help as to why...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`data-err-arrow="valuehere"` will return value with:

```
.data('errArrow')
```

`data-errArrow="valuehere"` since there is no dash will return with:

```
.data('errarrow');
```

Because there is no dash the key gets transformed to all lowercase.

http://jsfiddle.net/txo5sxp0/

This isn't the jQuery code but just gives you an idea of what it is doing:

```
function CamelCase(str) {

    var key;
    var data = str.split("-");

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            key = data[i].toLowerCase();
        } else {
            key += (data[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + data[i].slice(1)).toString();
        }
    }
    return key
}

var datakey = 'err-arrow';
var datakey2 = 'errArrow';

console.log(CamelCase(datakey)); //returns errArrow
console.log(CamelCase(datakey2)); //returns errarrow
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5jum59s4/

Comment: I reverted back to naming it as data-err-arrow.  But this is indeed the explanation and answer I was looking for.